# UiTableView load many cell and MemoryWarning

Tags: iphone, ios

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PostCount *post=[listArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Cell%d_%d_%@_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row,post.foreignId,[listArr count]];
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Cell_%d_%@",indexPath.row,post.foreignId];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NSLog(@"indexPath.row++++++++=%d",indexPath.row);

        TimeLineGraphicView *gview=[[TimeLineGraphicView alloc]init];
        gview.tag=indexPath.row+1000;
        gview.delegate=self;

        [cell addSubview:gview];

        int Allheight =[ModelClass returnGraphicViewHeight_timeLine:post];
        gview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, Allheight);
        [gview setViewStyle:post];
    }

    TimeLineGraphicView *gview=(TimeLineGraphicView *)[cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row+1000];
    gview.lab_time.text=[ModelClass intervalSinceNow:post.when btime:0];

    //NSLog(@"intervalSinceNow=%@  ",[ModelClass intervalSinceNow:post.when btime:0]);
    //NSLog(@"post.when=%@  gview=%@  gview.lab_time.text=%@",post.when,gview, gview.lab_time.text);   

    return cell;

}
```

hello,if i use the above code  if i have many cell, TimeLineGraphicView *gview=[[TimeLineGraphicView alloc]init] can increase memory，because when i load many cell for example first i load 15 cell,then add 15 cell then add 15 cell and so  on,it give me  didReceiveMemoryWarning,can you good practice to deal with the problem

Comment: Well Well Well, you are not releasing 'TimeLineGraphicView'. :-/

Comment: i am use ARC,how to release

Comment: You are not reusing the already created cells. Everytime you are creating new cells for all indexpath. So if you have 1000 cells you are creating 1000 different cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are implementing the things are not right.

- Why don't you subclass UITableViewCell ? Let's say, in your case why not a "TimelineGraphicTableviewCell" ?
- Adding your "TimeLineGraphicView" as a subView to the contentView of the cell can be done there.
- Set the frame  or such of the subView, in layoutSubviews of the custom class.
- In `– cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can just create it and set the data.!

I think if you implement things in the proper way, tableview should not show any memory warning no matter how many lines there are..!

If you are still unclear on customizing tableViewCells, just google it, you will find tons of tutorials.

Good luck..!

Comment: tahnk you,if i can use  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableViewCell";
        CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

Answer (score 1):

You do not release the cell

```
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

---

You do not release the view

```
[cell addSubview:gview];
[gview release];
```

Comment: i am use arc,can you give more detail